# How open *.sh *.py files in terminal Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: command-line, 13.04, .sh

In Ubuntu 12.10, after doing the `chmod a+x ./*.sh` command there was two options showing when double on `*.sh` file (Open in terminal - display)

But in Ubuntu 13.04 even after doing `chmod a+x` command, it still open in the text editor

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the new file manager, called Files, will only show you those files in the text editor.

In order to change this you need to open your File Manager Preferences window. In the image you can see the behavior options regarding executable text files. Set the option to "Ask each time" and the old behavior will be restored.

[image: Preferences]